# Gstreamer basic tutorial gives blank screen

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, video-processing

I have the following gstreamer basic tutorial. When I compile and run the program, I am only getting a blank screen. The same happens when I use mplayer, but I supply -vo x11 option to it and it works well(for mplayer). So, I am guessing the issue gstreamer is also the same. So, my question is..."What should I do to tell the program that my output driver is x11?" How do I get rid of the blank screen?

Thanks

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Build the pipeline */
  /*
    pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("playbin2 uri=http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm", NULL);
  */
    pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("playbin2 uri=file:///home/mylogin/gstreamerstuff/sintel_trailer-480p.webm", NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Free resources */
  if (msg != NULL)
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this code, before setting the pipeline to playing.

```
{
    GstElement* vsink = gst_element_factory_make ("ximagesink", NULL);
    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (pipeline), "video-sink", vsink, NULL);
}
```

The above code makes sure that the pipeline uses the GstElement called ximagesink.
This element (type = sink) is X11 based and dumps (to screen) the incoming buffers using 
X11 APIs

Comment: @cotigao, An explanation of what it does would be appreciated. It works for this example, but for a differernt example or command line, its not always working. Thanks!

Comment: user763410, can you please post the scenarios where it isn't working?